# array always pointing to the first index even though index is incremented

Tags: arrays, mips

For some reason, ($t3) is always outputting 1 even though $t2 is incremented. I don't understand why.

Here's the code:

```
.data
myArray1: .word 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
myArray2: .word 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
newline: .asciiz "\n"
.text
main:
li  $s1, 5
li  $s0, 1
la  $a1, myArray1
la  $a2, myArray2
loop:
beq $s0, $s1, exit  
sll $t0, $s0, 2 # $t0 = i * 4
sub $t2, $s0, 1
sll $t2, $t2, 2 # $t2 = (i-1)*4
add $t1, $a1, $t0   # $t1 = A[i]
add $t3, $a1, $t2   # $t3 = A[i-1]

move $a0, $t2
li  $v0, 1
syscall
jal newLine

lw  $a0, ($t3)
li  $v0, 1
syscall
jal newLine

add $t4, $a2, $t0   # $t4 = B[i]
lw  $t5, ($t3)
lw  $t6, ($t4)
add $t7, $t5, $t6 # $t7 = A[i-1] - B[i]
sw  $t7, ($t1)  # A[i] = $t7
addi    $s0, $s0, 1
j   loop
exit:
li  $v0, 10
syscall
newLine:
la  $a0, newline
li  $v0, 4
syscall
jr  $ra
```

I've added a section of code to output ($t3) and $t2 and even though $t2 is going up ($t3) is never changing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really sure what you're trying to do. But what's actually happening is that `$t7` always has the value 1 at `sw  $t7, ($t1)  # A[i] = $t7`, so you keep overwriting the next value in `myArray1` with 1.

Consider the case `i==1`:

- `A[i-1] == A[0] == 1`
- `B[i] == B[1] == 0`
- `A[i-1] + B[i] == 1 + 0 == 1`

Then, on the next iteration when `i==2`:

- `A[i-1] == A[1] == 1`  (because you set it to 1 on the previous iteration)
- `B[i] == B[2] == 0`
- `A[i-1] + B[i] == 1 + 0 == 1`

And so on.